# Sensor to detect vehicle occupants from external viewpoint?

Tags: sensor

Trying to solve for a project of mine. Thermal imaging (long wave infrared) sensors cannot pass through the metal skin/structure of a car, glass windows seem too reflective as well. I'm trying to find a safe, portable sensing technology that will allow me to tell if a car is occupied by one or more persons. False positives such as detecting a pet/animal in the car would be tolerable in this case.

Comment: A regular camera or near IR can see very well through the windows.

Comment: "I'm trying to find... technology that would allow me to tell if a car is occupied by one or more persons." No sensor in the world would make that decision. This is where computer vision and artificial intelligence comes into place. You can tell the computer how to detect if there's more than one person by performing some type of image processing algorithm utilizing a sensor but you cannot find a sensor that will automatically do this for you. But as far as finding that particular sensor to help you gather data, good luck finding something because I'm not aware of a solution either.

Comment: I need the data or image of the occupants to build the ML/DL model. I'm not expecting the sensor itself to tell me if it's a person or not.

Answer (score 2):

No solution;

I think that defies Physics as the attenuation of IR is high thru metal and being an excellent heat conductor tends to spread fast with external solar, engine and winter interior heat is often much stronger than the occupants.  It would be like trying to detect a 1ns pulse thru a 1 Hz LPF.  Glass would be like 10kHz filter.

A visual camera with multiple views and human head recognition might be possible but very low SNR.  A dummy could pass.

> There are a hundred really"cool" uses of thermal imaging but impossible thru a car.  here a local comic [Engineer has a great video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPNEakwZR7A)

Comment: I was thinking of a digital camera with a NIR bandpass filter and use a NIR illuminator to get past the window reflection of the car. However, this is really tricky because the optimal detection scenario is from a perspective facing the rear of the car or the driver-side and rear of the vehicle.

Comment: Is there any tech out there that allows for remote spectometry - i.e. take some form of laser, aim it into the passenger compartment and try to detect CO2 levels (i.e. human respiration leads to higher CO2 levels)?

Comment: Not likely with a remote external detector due to path loss and ambient levels

Comment: Human heads are round. Use about 100 horizontal stripes, find the top 20, those likely at roof and top of doors and those 18 stripes in between. Examine those 18 stripes for "round" occlusions.